# Can anyone tell me what font this is, it is a hotel sign in Lanzarote

Tags: font-identification

I have tried looking at various on-line font finders but no luck.

I have used the usual and tried cutting the image down but nothing recognises it. I have tried with WhatTheFont, Identifont and What Font is.

The logo is a sign on the hotel La Isla Y El Mar in Lanzarote.
Thanks for your help

[image: La Isla]

Comment: Looking at the differences in the `A` letters... might not be a font.

Comment: I suspect it's real hand-lettering, not a font - normally when hand-lettering-style fonts swap in letter variants to make the text look more natural, they do it by letter pairs using ligatures, but here we have two `LA` combinations and both are different. If it *is* a font, they made the letters vary in a way I've not seen before. (if it *is* hand lettering, they did a very good job, it's very consistent!)